# SVN Propset for editing Log messages WITH DREAMHOST

Tags: svn, dreamhost

So i have an account at dreamhost and have some projects there.  Does anyone know how to make it so i can edit log messages.  I get this error and since i do not understand how to fix it, and google hasnt seemed to help me, i default to here.

```
Error:  
DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent  
At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged  
Error setting property 'log':  
Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges; ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook
```

I have done the change suggested below by renaming my pre-revprop-change.tmpl to just pre-revprop-change and i get a new error

```
Error:  
DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent  
At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged  
Error setting property 'log':  
Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 255) with no output
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a file called `pre-revprop-change.tmpl` in your repository `hooks` directory, rename it to the `pre-revprop-change` and log changing should start working.

Comment: I get a new error now.  `DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent  
At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged  
Error setting property 'log':  
Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 255) with no output`

Comment: I guess file `pre-revprop-change` does not have execution rights. Run `chmod +x pre-revprop-change`.